# matrix to Euler angles

Tags: linear-algebra

I've rotation angles for a sequence of frame data and/or keyframes I need to multiply all of them by some rotation matrix and store new rotation angles values.The task looks very simple: just use a math function to convert produced matrices to angles. It works but.. not as I need. For example if initial rotation were smooth curves - they become broken/disordered after transform and further interpolation is ruined. After experimenting I see the matrix→>euler is an ambiguos operation, For example

vector3 euler = Matrix2Euler(myMatrix);

matrix testM = Euler2Matrix(euler);

Yes, the testM will be equal to initial myMatrix. However

matrix testM = Euler2Matrix(myEuler);

vector3 euler = Matrix2Euler(testM);

The returned "euler" can be far away of original myEuler.

Please suggest a math/theory to solve this

Thx

Comment: Your question is a little cryptic. The functions you use 'matrix2Euler" and its reciprocal come from a programming language (which one ?) with its peculiarities that we are not aware of. Besides, on the theoretical point of view, have you heard about the "gimbal lock" issue ?

Comment: Yes, I'm a programmer, not a mathematic. There are several implementations of matrix2Euler functions but essentially they all return "nearest Euler" solution (a triple of angles). That is correct and produces same rotation, but it's inacceptable for a sequence/animation, initially smooth curves are broken. How can I get "alternate" set(s) of Euler's angles?